# About SEO questions asked in the wrong place

Tags: feature-request, migration

There are many SEO questions asked on this site, and many of them should be moved to Webmasters.

1. Someone is nearly systematically voting down such questions. I think that this is a misuse of the voting feature; it is not because a question is asked in the wrong place that it is necessarily a bad question.
2. Having to vote for those questions to be closed and moved to Webmasters by several users is a lot of work which has to be performed every day, and people give up... It is too inefficient!

Could SO implement a simple migrate button that would be accessible to Webmasters participants with high reputations (or SO participants with a silver or gold SEO badge)?

Comment: Do you really need to call out a specific user?

Comment: What's the issue with that when there is misuse of the voting feature?

Comment: I see a lot of simply awful questions in that tag. Many of them should be downvoted and closed, and they should not be migrated to another site. This is not a misuse of the voting system, and what you're proposing would probably lead to a lot of bad migrations.

Comment: Downvoting means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Well they haven't researched if they ask here, and it's not usefull here.

Comment: @JVerstry as far as I know voting is still anonymous so you're speculating where those votes come from. One of the down vote reasons is *not useful* I tend to use that as a valid reason for questions that are not useful for visitors of SO. It is very well possible more users apply their votes in a similar fashion. If you keep it generic you can still make your point without naming specific users.

Comment: @JVerstry Voting is anonymous so you can't truly know who downvoted a question unless they say they did. You shouldn't assume to know who it was because more than likely you're wrong.

Comment: @rene Bring me evidence that's its not him and then we can argue about speculation.

Comment: It's *not* misuse to down vote terrible, off-topic questions. It helps the roomba clean them up once they're closed.

Comment: There are plenty of questions in the tag voted down to -3 or lower. It's not just one person.

Comment: @JVerstry you bring it up, I don't understand why I need to bring in the evidence....

Comment: I don't see the reaction of the community as being constructive here... well...

Comment: @JVerstry Since when is it guilty until proven innocent?

Comment: I regularly downvote bad SEO questions on Stack Overflow. And so should you!

Comment: Downvoting off topic questions is completely acceptable.  FYI, I have the tag in my RSS feed and regularly downvote/VTC off topic questions.  Also downvote answers to obviously off-topic questions. (edit) *Bring me evidence* lol @ u.

Comment: Hey, look, it's OP encouraging people to ask off-topic questions! http://i.stack.imgur.com/YvEkG.png

Answer (score 4):

> Someone is nearly systematically voting down such questions.

That might actually be me. [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) is one of the tags I frequently sweep through, because it is a magnet for spam and terrible off-topic questions ([e-commerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/e-commerce) is another real winner). I try to do this proactively because it's easy to make the call as to what does and does not belong and remove it before the community has to deal with it. For example, here are some real winners from the last couple of weeks:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451203/are-you-interested-for-seo-services-get-your-website-on-first-page-on-google
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406842/ikitelli-çilingir-http-www-ikitellicilingir-com-sitem-sıra-düştü-sıradan-bir-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406842/ikitelli-%C3%A7ilingir-http-www-ikitellicilingir-com-sitem-s%C4%B1ra-d%C3%BC%C5%9Ft%C3%BC-s%C4%B1radan-bir-s)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32477010/what-and-why-is-keyword-important-for-seo

That's not to say that I'll downvote a question simply because it's off topic. There's just a lot of really poorly asked questions there.

Regarding the person you accuse of misusing votes, I should point out they helped to flag at least one of the above spam posts, and I can't argue with their close votes on things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443771/i-need-help-for-seo-optimization). Again, there happens to be a lot of very bad questions that come into that tag.

As to why we don't migrate more of them, frankly I don't think that Webmasters would appreciate getting our bad SEO questions. The first rule of migrations is "don't migrate crap", and moderators from other sites get irritated when we direct our trash their way. I know that the topic of elevated migration privileges for established members of other sites has been discussed before, though, but I can't find a link to it right now.

Comment: But where else should I ask whether using pastel shades on my web site will hurt my SEO?

Comment: OP's a jerk http://i.stack.imgur.com/YvEkG.png